# How to sort a list of strings by a part of a string

Tags: python

```
string =["age 12, city1, 10",
           "age 0, city4, 2",
           "age 16, city3, 8",
           "age 9, city2, 1",
           ]
```

I need to sort the list based on their age.

Comment: Why isn't this a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, from the docs: [Both list.sort() and sorted() have a key parameter to specify a function (or other callable) to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `lambda` function to `key` parameter of `sorted` builtin. In the lambda function, split the value on `,` exactly once, then take the first value, split it again on space  , then take the last value, convert it to `int`

```py
>>> sorted(string, key=lambda x: int(x.split(',', maxsplit=1)[0].split(' ')[-1]))

['age 0, city4, 2', 'age 9, city2, 1', 'age 12, city1, 10', 'age 16, city3, 8']
```

Answer (score 1):

use `lambda` function.

Age number always starts at 5th character and `,` is the terminating character. Extract that number and sort on it.

```
string.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[4:x.index(',')]))
print(string)
```

> ['age 0, city4, 2', 'age 9, city2, 1', 'age 12, city1, 10', 'age 16, city3, 8']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`:

```
import re
...
string.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'(\d+)',re.findall(r'age (\d+)',x)[0])[0]))
```

Or by:

```
string.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'age (\d+)',x.split(',')[0])[0]))
```

Both output:

```
['age 0, city4, 2', 'age 9, city2, 1', 'age 12, city1, 10', 'age 16, city3, 8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by extracting age from 4rth index to index before 1st ','

```py
string.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[4:].split(',', 1)[0]))
print(string)
```